# Initial and final sub-spaces of a partial isometry

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and assume $H_0$ and $K_0$ are two sub-spaces of $H$ with dim$H_0$=dim$K_0$.

Question: Is there any partial isometry $u$ whose initial projection is $H_0$ and final projection is $K_0$?

Comment: What are the initial and final projections of $u$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the obvious construction works:

Let $(e_i)_{i\in I}$ and $(f_i)_{i\in I}$ be orthonormal bases of $H_0$ and $K_0$ respectively, and complete them to ONBs $(e_i)_{i\in J}$ and $(f_i)_{i\in J}$ of $H$. Define $ve_i=f_i$ for $i\in I$ and $ve_i=0$ for $i\in J\setminus I$. It is easily seen that
$$v^\ast f_i=\begin{cases}e_i,&\text{for }i\in I,\\0,&\text{for }i\in J\setminus I.\end{cases}
$$
It follows that $v^\ast v$ is the projection onto $\overline{\mathrm{lin}}\{e_i\mid i\in I\}=H_0$ and $vv^\ast$ the projection onto $\overline{\mathrm{lin}}\{f_i\mid i\in I\}=K_0$.